# Django templating + Vue templating for the same content for SEO reasons

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm in the process of building a Django app with limited Javascript interactivity, and am looking at how to incorporate Vue templating along with Django templating for the same content.

Imagine an infinite scroll page, where SEO is very important. Django is great at solving this problem since it is per definition a server side framework. However, how would you enrich a page rendered by Django with Vue, provided that both of these technologies need to render the same content? Django would in this case render for the SEO crawlers, right before Vue takes over, Vue "hydrates" these components and make them interactive. After this happens, subsequent content that is fetched asynchronously with AJAX will also be templated using Vue.

I have done some research without finding sufficient information on how to solve this:

- https://vsupalov.com/vue-js-in-django-template/ which is where some parts of the code sample below is based off of
- https://medium.com/quick-code/crud-app-using-vue-js-and-django-516edf4e4217 which outlines that combining django and vue seems to work pretty well together
- https://medium.com/@rodrigosmaniotto/integrating-django-and-vuejs-with-vue-cli-3-and-webpack-loader-145c3b98501a

I don't get the sense that these sources are talking about SEO, or rather if they are, they utilize Vue templating only where the content is not SEO heavy(like opening a modal).

Below is an initial idea of these two technologies rendering the same content in different ways. Since Vue has the `delimiter` option I felt like maybe there is a way to combine the two(as to avoid the collision of templating syntax).

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Django and Vue test</title>
</head>
<body>

{% if names %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var names = {{ names_json|safe }};
    </script>

    <div id="app">

        <!-- This list is for SEO purposes, let's say 'above the fold' content contained in a responsive grid before an infinite scroll is triggered -->
        <h2>Django list</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for name in names %}
                <li>
                    <div>
                        <img src="avatar.jpg">
                        <div>
                            <div>{{ name }}@test.se</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

        <!-- This list is supposed to somehow 'hydrate' the django template content, in order to enrich the template with interactive VueJS. When the client Vue instance is instantiated/mounted, the idea is that only these elements populate the page, and not the SSR ones -->
        <h2>Vue list</h2>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="name in names">
                <div v-on:click="greet(name)">
                    <img src="avatar.jpg">
                    <div>
                        <div>[[ name ]]@test.se</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                names: names,
            },
            methods: {
                greet: function (name) {
                    console.log('Vue says hello from ' + name + '!')
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Am I thinking about this in the wrong way, or do any of you have any guidance for me?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: have you considered server side rendering? look at nuxtjs

Comment: I have. The thing is I'm very comfortable with Django and the way it handles SSR already. So I figured maybe there's a way to combine that with Vue, since Vue is very lightweight. Edit: If possible I would like to avoid making the frontend into a full fledged SPA.

Comment: without using webpack you are already missing out a lot, this way you can perfectly work it out, but something like nuxt should be the ultimate option.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm understanding correctly, your suggestion is to make it server side rendered by JS within nuxtjs, and then serve the data dynamically to this nuxtjs app with an api from within django? Also, you're saying "this way you can perfectly work it out", but how?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

views.py

```py
def show_customers(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    context = {
        'customers': customers,
    }

    return render(request, "app/customers.html", context)
```

template: `customers.html`

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Customer list</title>
        {% if DEBUG %}
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
        {% else %}
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
        {% endif %}
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        {% for customer in customers|slice:":3" %}
            <p>
                {{ customer.id }} - {{ customer.user.username }}
            </p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% verbatim %}
        <script id="more-customers-template" type="text/template">
            <p>
                {{ customer.id }} - {{ customer.name }}
            </p>
        </script>
        {% endverbatim %}

    </div>
    <div class="issue-more-posts" id="more-customers">
        <customer
                v-for="customer in customers"
                v-bind:customer="customer"
                v-bind:key="customer.id"
        ></customer>
        <button @click="loadMorecustomer">
            SHOW MORE customers
        </button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Vue.component('customer', {
            props: {
                customer: Object,
                nextPage: String
            },
            template: "#more-customers-template"
        });

        var customerMore = new Vue({
            el: '#more-customers',
            data: {
                customers: []
            },
            methods: {
                loadMorecustomer: function () {
                    this.customers = [{name: 'Some dynamic data', id: 1}]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This code is for demonstration purposes, you will need to separate the JS code and the Vue Template code.

EDIT: I found a really good article about this, even cleaner. [vuejs-and-django](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/build-an-app-with-vuejs-and-django-part-one)